# Download image from "no-hotlink" url

Tags: c#

I try to download image on stooorage.com using following code

```
Webclient wc = new Webclient();
wc.DownloadFile(Link,Filepath);
```

But this is no-hotlink site ?

Link to test:

http://www.stooorage.com/show/3105/11956084_ngoc_han.jpg

Need a trick :(

Comment: You might need to spoof your referrer to point to the stoooarage.com url to indicate that the request comes actually from their own site.

Comment: Note that if you're going to bypass the host's enforcement of the host's rules, the host may take technical measures to prevent you from doing so. Any answer you get may therefore stop working at any time. Is there any particular reason you want to download an image from a host that doesn't want to let you do what you want to do? Can you not simply put it on a host that doesn't have such blocks in place?